# Drawing lines along the cursor path in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, kineticjs

I am using KineticJS to implement a drawing application. I have used it to draw shapes, straight lines. I have used way described in [KineticJS - Drawing Lines with Mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311535/kineticjs-drawing-lines-with-mouse) to draw straight lines. But now my requirement is to draw line along the mouse path! What should be the procedure for that? Can we use Kinetic.Path to do that?

Following code is used to draw straight lines,

```
    var Object,startingPoint;
    var down = false;

    layer.on("mousedown", function(e) {
        down = true;
        Object = new Kinetic.Line({
            points: [e.layerX, e.layerY,e.layerX+1, e.layerY+1],
            stroke: "red"
        });

        layer.add(Object);
    });

    layer.on("mousemove", function(e) {
         if (down) {
                var x = e.layerX;
                var y = e.layerY;
                Object.getPoints()[1].x = e.layerX;
                Object.getPoints()[1].y = e.layerY;
                down = true;
                layer.draw();
         }        
    });

    layer.on("mouseup", function(e) {
        down = false;
    });
```

I have replaced  Kinetic.Line with Kinetic.Path to achieve the target. But it didn't work.

Comment: Sure you can.  What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have added the code to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: put together a jsfiddle or jsbin and people will help

Answer (score 0):

if you need to add points to a line you can do this:

```
  var points = line.getPoints();
  var pos = stage.getUserPosition();
  points = points.push(pos.x, pos.y);
  line.setPoints(points);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how I implemented it. The key is to use spline shape of kineticJS and push points in it during mousemove and mouseup. ev._x, ev._y are the x, and y points calculated in the light of this post 
[Tracking mouse position in canvas when no surrounding element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085689/tracking-mouse-position-in-canvas-when-no-surrounding-element-exists/5086147#5086147)

Please let me know if it helps

```
    tools.pencil = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;
    var drawObject;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
     drawObject = new DrawObject();
     drawObject.Tool = DrawTool.Pencil;
     tool.started = true;
     drawObject.currentState = DrawState.Started;
     drawObject.StartX = ev._x;
     drawObject.StartY = ev._y;
     tool.DrawIt(drawObject);

   };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started) {
           drawObject.currentState = DrawState.Inprogress;
           drawObject.CurrentX = ev._x;
           drawObject.CurrentY = ev._y;
           tool.DrawIt(drawObject);


    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started) {
            tool.started = false;
            drawObject.currentState = DrawState.Completed;
             drawObject.CurrentX = ev._x;
            drawObject.CurrentY = ev._y;
           tool.DrawIt(drawObject);
       }
    };

    this.mouseout = function (ev) {
        if (tool.started) {
        }
        tool.started = false;

    };


    this.DrawIt = function (drawObject) {

            switch (drawObject.currentState) {
                case DrawState.Started:
                    var x= drawObject.StartX, 
                        y = drawObject.StartY;
                    var pencil = new Kinetic.Spline({
                        points: [{
                            x: x,
                            y: y
                        }],
                        stroke: 'red',
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        lineCap: 'round',
                        tension: 1,
                        name: shapes.length
                    });

                    drawObject.Shape = pencil;
                    layer.add(pencil);
                    layer.draw();


                    break;
                case DrawState.Inprogress:
                case DrawState.Completed:
                    var x = drawObject.CurrentX,
                        y = drawObject.CurrentY;

                    var pencil = drawObject.Shape;
                    pencil.attrs.points.push({ x: x, y: y });
                    pencil.setPoints(pencil.attrs.points);
                    layer.draw();
                    if (drawObject.currentState == DrawState.Completed) {
                        // dosomething
                    }

                    break;
            }
```

Where draw object is simple empty function in javascript

```
function DrawObject()
{
}
```

and drawstate is all the available state of pencil tool

```
var DrawState =
{
 Started: 0,
 Inprogress: 1,
 Completed: 2
}
```

and "layer" is simple KineticJS layer already added in KineticJS stage