# Kineticjs: how to use pen tool using kineticjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I would like to use pen tool (like photo shop) using kineticjs,
I don't have any idea about how to achieve this.

whether it is possible or not?.  If possible means help me to find out the solution.

I am using kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js and kinetic-v5.0.1.js files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete solution.

Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/JSdc2/LjJ8W/

```
 document.body.addEventListener( 'mousedown', startListening, false );

    // -- /init


    // add ins for testing

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({

        width: window.innerWidth - 30,
        height: window.innerHeight - 70,
        container: 'container'

    });

    var freeHandLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({

        x:0,
        y:0,
        width: window.innerWidth/2,
        height: window.innerHeight/2

    });

    var background = new Kinetic.Rect({

        width: window.innerWidth - 30,
        height: window.innerHeight - 70,
        fill: '#DDDDDD'

    });

    freeHandLayer.add( background );
    stage.add( freeHandLayer );

    // -- /add ins


  var ctx = freeHandLayer.getContext('2d');

    // ------- freeHand Functions
    // thanks to http://nick.zoic.org/

    function draw_marker(x, y, r) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0";
        ctx.fill();

    }

    function draw_segment(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#0F0";
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

    }

    // -----

    var pos, ox, oy, xys, nx, ny, dx, dy, dd;
    var points = [];
    var xnums = [];
    var ynums = [];


    function startListening() {

        points=[]; // clear array 
        xnums=[];
        ynums=[];

        pos = stage.getPointerPosition();

        ox = pos.x;
        oy = pos.y;
        xnums[0] = ox;
        ynums[0] = oy;

        document.body.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', startListening );
        document.body.addEventListener( 'mousemove', handleMovement, false );

    }

    function handleMovement() {

        document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', finalizeSpline, false );

         pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
         nx = pos.x;
         ny = pos.y;

         dx = nx - ox;
         dy = ny - oy;
         dd = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

        if (dd > 10) {
            draw_segment(ox, oy, nx, ny);
            xnums.push(nx);
            ynums.push(ny);
            ox = nx;
            oy = ny;
        }
    }

    var ID = 0;
    var customShape = [];

    function finalizeSpline() {

        ID++;

        document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMovement );
        document.body.removeEventListener('mouseup', finalizeSpline );

        for ( var i = 0; i < xnums.length; i++ ) {

            points.push (xnums[ i ]);
            points.push (ynums[ i ]);

        }

        // Create a Group for the new shape to live inside

        customShape[ID] = new Kinetic.Group({

            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            rotationDeg: 0

         });

        customShape[ID].id = 'L06customShape' + ID;
        customShape[ID].attrs.id = 'L06customShape' + ID;
        customShape[ID].selectable = true; 
        customShape[ID].selectStyle = "group" ;
        customShape[ID].colorable = true;
        customShape[ID].colorStyle = "single" ;
        customShape[ID].description = "A custom shape." ;
        customShape[ID].difficulty = 1;

        // Create the shape from user input

        var spline = new Kinetic.Line({

            id:'L06spline' + ID,
            points: points, // uses the points we collected from user pointer movement
            tension: 0, // TO DO: don't like the range Kinetic offers 0 to 1, create something better.
            closed: false,
            fill: '#ccc',
            draggable: true

          });

        // add some tweaks

        customShape[ID].on('mousedown touchstart', function( e ) { signals.mouseDown.dispatch( this, e ); });
        customShape[ID].on('mouseup touchend', function( e ) { signals.mouseUp.dispatch( this, e ); });

        customShape[ID].add( spline );
        customShape[ID].className = 'Blob';

        freeHandLayer.add( customShape[ID] );
    document.body.addEventListener( 'mousedown', startListening, false );

    }

       function getPointerPos( e ) {

        var position = ctx.getBoundingClientRect();

        return {

            x: e.clientX - position.left,
            y: e.clientY - position.top

        };
    }
```

Comment: Oh right, and if you think it's too 'jerky' and not smooth enough, change the line that says "if (dd > 10) {" to a lower number. That "10" is the space between collected screen points, so if you don't move at least 10 pixels, nothing gets drawn. So for instance, set it to 5, the line gets a lot smoother.

Comment: Oh wait if you mean the 'pen' tool like the one that lets you edit nodes with the little handles, you'd have to merge something like I posted above, and add in this kind of functionality: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-modify-curves-with-anchor-points-using-kineticjs/

Comment: In theory, you could look at this code which still shows the 'handles' and make them draggable. http://nick.zoic.org/html5/mouse-events-canvas-and-splines-in-javascript-html5/

Comment: thank you JSdc. is that any point how to do the same thing in kinetic layer

Answer (score 1):

What did you try? What did you find after you searched? Anyway, You'll have to listen for mouse events on the stage and then draw a `Kinetic.Line`. Those two questions on Stackoverflow should help you, in case you didn't see them.

[KineticJS - Drawing Lines with Mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311535/kineticjs-drawing-lines-with-mouse)

[Kinetic.js - Draw a freehandline by following mousepointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131177/kinetic-js-draw-a-freehandline-by-following-mousepointer)